# Babel doesn't work, returns CLI errors

Tags: npm, webpack, command-line-interface, babeljs

I installed Babel locally in my project with the following command:

```
npm install babel-cli babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

This gives me the following output in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel --presets es2015 src -d lib"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.2"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure, but it looks like it was installed successfully. But when I try to run `npm run babel` I get:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "babel"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2

npm ERR! missing script: babel
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
nam ERR!     /Path/To/My/Project/npm-debug.log
```

Why doesn't Babel work? In the package.json file it is included:

Comment: Have you defined it in your webpack config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack getting started, import error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775977/webpack-getting-started-import-error)

Comment: If not, check out the answer to a (similar issue)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/40776313/2902660]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you run `npm run babel`

and it said `npm ERR! missing script: babel`

may be you meant this: `npm run build`

---

Two things to ponder:

1. [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

   > This runs an arbitrary command from a package's "scripts" object.
2. [babel](https://babeljs.io/) is not a script in your `package.json`, but a transpiler for JavaScript which converts ES6 to ES5.

so if you run `npm run build`, that will execute the `build` command defined here:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib"
  },
```

I also see there is a **duplicate** of `scripts` object.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to run an installed npm executables.

The easiest way is to install it also globally. In your case you need only `babel-cli` to be available in command line. so `npm install -g babel-cli` will do.

If you want to install it only locally, `babel` executable is also available on `node_modules/.bin/babel`. But surely it's much of typing for a command.

The other way that you are trying is to use [`npm-run-scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script). In this case you have to define the script in your `package.json`. You already have a `build` script that you can run like `npm run build`. So for `npm run babel` you need the same form of script definition:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib",
    "babel": "babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js" // For example
}
...
```

This is used mostly to have a shorthand for a command that you want to run frequently like a build script.

You can also provide additional arguments to an npm script with this syntax:

`npm run babel -- --presets es2015`

Notice the additional `--` here.

There is still another option where you can install a package once globally and link to it from different projects:

`npm install -g babel-cli` and in your project direcotory `npm link babel-cli`.

The most common way is the easiest one where you install executable packages (command line interfaces) both globally and locally.